# Color.ParseColor() - NullPointerException

Tags: android, parsing, colors, nullpointerexception

I have this field declared:

```
private String textColor = "#FFEFEFEF";
```

and in a method is:

```
tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(textColor));
```

Im getting NullPointerException at Color.PareseColor(). What do I do wrong? It should work like this.

Comment: Yes, there is also tv.setText(), tv.setTypeface() etc. and it works. Only the color doesnt work.

Comment: Oh, i know whats wrong. One of constructors reset textColor to null if inflated from XML and textColor attribute is missing.

Answer (score 0):

One of constructors was resetting textColor to null when inflated from XML and textColor attribute is missing.

```
textColor = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.incredible.fontmetrics", "textColor");
```